# Cannot use keyboard within Qt app without sudo

Tags: c++, linux, qt, keyboard, beagleboneblack

I have an embedded Qt application crosscompiled that runs on BeagleBone Black. It works OK, but one thing - it doesn't accept keyboard input if I won't run in directly on BeagleBone Black preceding with `sudo`. This is a problem because:

- I cannot remote debug application and use connected keyboard, as it doesn't work,
- I cannot use keyboard when the app is in `rc.local` file to boot at startup (even though `sudo` is used there).

What can I try next?

My `/etc/enviroment` content is here:

```
QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=IntelliMouse:/dev/input/mouse0
QWS_KEYBOARD=LinuxInput:/dev/tty
TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
```

Although I have tried many different configurations for `QWS_KEYBOARD`. The keyboard I would like to use is `/dev/input/event1`.

Comment: Check permissions on /dev/input/event1 then?

Comment: `crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13, 65 Mar  1 21:45 event1`

Comment: You need a debug build of Qt, and you need to trace into the platform code to figure out why the keyboard access fails. It's possibly a very simple problem to fix. I don't understand why remote debugging won't work if the keyboard doesn't work. You control the debugger from your host, not from the target.

Comment: Thats not what I meant. The keyboard works only if i run the app on the board typing in `sudo ./myapp -qws`. They keyboard doesnt work if I remote debug or run the same line using ssh from remote pc. I can press the keyboard keys but they are not registered in the app, but go behind the app to the console (there is no x server). I have no idea how to fix this. The biggest problem is that when i run the app from `rc.local' using  `sudo ./myapp -qws` the keyboard doesnt work as well... How can i degug keyboard input if the app doesnt see it?

Comment: I'd run strace on myapp and see what it's doing with /dev/input/event1 then.

Comment: `/dev/input/event1` is responsive 100%, because I have tested it with tools from `#include<linux/input.h>`. The problem is the Qt doesnt see the events, for example `QFileSystemWatcher` doesnt detect changes on `/dev/input/event1`

Comment: You can run other apps using that device as a non-root user?

Comment: Its not abot being or not being root- if i werent root the qt app wouldnt even start. So when i run it, i am root. But for some reason i cant use the keyboard if not executed directly and not via rc script.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @OndrejBozek Hi. No I did not, I had to implement a c style keyboard watcher in order to capture the key events. Soon I will be trying Qt 5.7 on Raspberry Pi with simmilar approach ( https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS ). I hope not to face this problem again.

Comment: I face this problem after update of KDE plasma 5.6 -> 5.7. Cant' fix it

Answer (score 0):

I also facing this issue. But in my situation, I use remote desktop from Windows OS to raspberry / beaglebone.

My solution (make sure at least you know how to configure ssh in raspberry) :

1. install xrdp (sudo apt-get install xrdp) on raspberry / beaglebone / other embedded linux
2. in PC instal xming (search sourceforge)
3. open XLaunch, select multiple windows > start no client > clipboard > finish
4. open putty >> session, enter host name / IP address, 
   putty >> SSH >> X11 >> check 'Enable X11 forwarding'
   putty >> click Open button
5. login ssh and then type qcreator

now the keyboard should be fine

Comment: This doesnt solve the issue completly, as one has to transfer X over to the host and still cannot use it at the target when debuging. ALso I think you are running qt creator on the target....