# Qt device watcher?

Tags: c++, qt, device, beagleboneblack, qfilesystemwatcher

Because of the problem I am experiencing described here [Cannot use keyboard within Qt app without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31161989/1036082) and here [Qt embedded linux event watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31191149/1036082) I was wondering either there is in Qt, an event watcher? I Have found library named [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) but it doesnt work with devices, only with regular files. Also I have found a 3rd party library for this [QDeviceWatcher](https://github.com/wang-bin/qdevicewatcher) but it only consists signals for when a new device is inserted or removed, not when it changes (for example I press a key). I need to watch a keyboard device `/dev/input/event1` for key strokes. I would apreciate all help!

Comment: I think you're looking for the wrong fix to your problem. You should debug why Qt can't reliably open `/dev/input/event1`.

Comment: @peppe I am trying to do that for over a week now and I cannot figure it out. This only occurs when i run the app remotelly through ssh or via rc.local script. I am not proud of this solution but its what i got left I believe.

Comment: You *can* attach to a running process using remote gdb, so you should be able to debug it. If you somehow can't debug it, you should post a question describing exactly what you're doing, and where does the debugging fail. You'll of course need a self-built debug Qt.